# Database access Java

Tags: java, database, transactions

I've got the following question. I got a little application which saves payments, dates and persons inside a database. Now I got the following POJO class:

```
public class Payment implements Serializable {

private int id;

private double payment;
private Date datum;
private String usage;
private String category;
private int importance;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public double getPayment() {
    return payment;
}

public void setPayment(double payment) {
    this.payment = payment;
}

public Date getDatum() {
    return datum;
}

public void setDatum(Date datum) {
    this.datum = datum;
}

public String getUsage() {
    return usage;
}

public void setUsage(String usage) {
    this.usage = usage;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public int getImportance() {
    return importance;
}

public void setImportance(int importance) {
    this.importance = importance;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("ID: ");
    sb.append(id);
    sb.append("\nPAYMENT: ");
    sb.append(payment);
    sb.append("\nDATE: ");
    sb.append(datum);
    sb.append("\nUSAGE: ");
    sb.append(usage);
    sb.append("\nCATEGORY: ");
    sb.append(category);
    sb.append("\nIMPORTANCE: ");
    sb.append(importance);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

So, I got also a class for my dates and persons. The question I've got is the following: Should I create for every Table in my database(in Java the Payment.class , Date.class and Person.class) a own transaction/access class which supports an `.saveOrUpdate()`, `.list()` or `.delete()` function?So maybe I got than a `PaymentRansaction.class` or an `PersonTransaction.class`.

Thanks for every help :)

Comment: Write what you need.

Comment: it doesn't hurt to have a simple model class for every table in DB. however its importance is based on how often you are going to use them .

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

Do you have **one** table with transactions, then **one** model should be sufficient.

Create methods to create the transactions for you depending on Payment or Person.

**BUT**

If you have more then 1 table go for multiple classess, each table it's own class.